# ios how to draw a line on a image in drawrect method

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView called imgView which was added by

```
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

when I draw line in view's `drawrect` method, the line shows below imgView, but i want it shows on imgView. ps: i also tried

```
 [self.view insertSubview:imgView atIndex:0];
```

which hides the imgView i.e I could see it on the view

```
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

and

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
```

that also didn't work.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Draw your image in the drawRect method, then draw the line.

```
[img drawAtPoint:your_point];

// Code to draw the line
```

Comment: i add many images into view and i need drag or move it and there some other operations on these images, in all words , i can't draw image to view in drawRect method. please help me! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but still, could be usefull to someone.

The reason why line is under image - is because everything you do in drawRect, will be below every subview. So if you would want a line on top of image, you would need to add to imageview an UIView subview class, in which You have corresponding drawrect with line drawing.